# Что делать если команда в телеграм была задана в группе, а бот отвечает в личных сообщениях? Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

````
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
#1
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
    elif message.text == "/help":
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    elif message.text == "/start":
                    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    else:
                            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")```
````

Comment: `from_user.id` отправляет в ЛС пользователю, а вам необходимо использовать `chat.id`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте документацию [Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)

Вы используете `message.from_user.id`, который возвращает ID человека, отправившего команду. А вам нужно вывести туда, откуда и была запрошена команда. В этом случае используйте `message.chat.id`, который всегда возвращает id чата, в котором была написана команда.